# Rails scope checking for no associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Category` model where a `category` may have some subcategories (`category.categories`). I want a scope that gives me all `Category`s that have no sub`categories`.

In other words, I can write

```
without_subcategories = Category.select{|category| category.categories.none?}
```

but I would like to write this as a `scope`. How do I do this?

In case it's not clear, this is my model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :categories, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: 'Category'
  scope :without_subcategories, lambda { WHAT GOES IN HERE? }
end
```

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2, activerecord and postgresql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best practice is minimize db queries by implementing a counter cache.
In rails this is super simple by adding an option `:counter_cache => true` to the belongs_to association. This assumes you create a `'categories_count'` integer column in your categories db table. Given this, your scope is trivial.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', :counter_cache => true
  has_many :categories, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: 'Category'
  scope :without_subcategories, where(categories_count: 0)
end
```

hope this helped.

Comment: You don't even need a `lambda` in this case, just `scope :without_subcategories, where(:categories_count => 0)` is sufficient.